# Haskell optional type parameter

Tags: haskell, parameterized-types

In haskell, how do you define an optional type parameter:

```
data Car a b c = Car { company :: a
                     , model :: b
                     , year :: c  
                     }
-- I want to return this type if `c` is not provided
data Car a b = Car { company :: a  
                   , model :: b
                   }
```

In above, I wanna have have an optional type `c` and based on whether it's provided or not return a slightly different type. How do I do this? Am I doing this totally wrong?

Comment: You can do this with `Maybe`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: but this will not factor out the `c` type parameter.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, what about structural typing? What if I have a function that only cares about `company` and should accept both of these?

Comment: I don't think it is possible "by default". You can search for libraries with key words like "extensible records", "variant" or "row polymorphism"

Comment: @norbertpy Why do you want to do this? In other words, why do you need two different `Car` types?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa, because I have so many combinations of Cars and I don't want to define a new type for every single one of them. `CarWithoutYear`, `CarWithoutModel`, `CarWithoutYearAndModel` seems a little crazy, doesn't it? I'm guessing either I don't understand type systems or this is how it should be? [Combinatorial Explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion)

Comment: @norbertpy Your first `data Car a b c = ...` already captures all of those, via `Car a b ()`, `Car a () c`, and `Car a () ()`, respectively.

Comment: @norbertpy Well, the thing to consider is that each of those combinations is a use-case you're going to have to handle anyway. Defining each of the possibilities as types (or perhaps a single sum type with multiple constructors) is actually helpful because it makes them explicit. But you're right, it's quite the Combinatorial Explosion. I think it's worth thinking about what benefit you'd get by making all the "attributes" optional.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa, thanks. Yeah. But I'm wondering why the same set of operation we can have on values cannot be done on types. Imagine I have two row types and I want to have a function that receives these two and return a new row type with their common properties. Then what?

Comment: @norbertpy Sorry, but it's just not clear what you're trying to achieve. Perhaps you can show a working example in another programming language.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa, never mind. You helped a lot :)

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but depending of what you want to achieve, you could switch to OCaml which has great polymorphic variants. I guess it's also present in ReasonML. https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lablexamples.html#sec46

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on what exactly you're asking, there are different approaches I'm familiar with. But first of all it's not clear to me that you want those types to be parameterized. i.e. I suspect what you really want is something like:

```
data Car = Car { company :: Company
               , model :: String
               , year :: Int  
               }
```

In particular it seems unlikely that you would need separate representations for the `year`.  If that's the case, then the answer to your question (how to make the year optional is:

```
data Car = Car { company :: Company
               , model :: String
               , year :: Maybe Int -- N.B. Maybe  
               }
```

If you're really asking about having a parameterized type which is optional then you can do something like this:

```
data Foo a = Foo Int Char a
```

Then you can use this as `Foo ()` when you wish to treat it as "a Foo without the last parameter". You can further make a newtype wrapper around it if you want.

```
newtype FooWithoutA = FooWithoutA (Foo ())
```

Since the unit type `()` has just a single value this indicates there's nothing of interest in that field.

---

Aside: You also might be interested in reading http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/10/the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types/ which will give you a sense of why different ways of structuring your data are equivalent, among other insights.

Comment: `Maybe` helps when I know what type I want. Just like a function that receives `values` and return `values`, I wanna have a type level function that receives `types` and returns different `types`.  Why is this so complicated?

Comment: Imagine I have two row types and I want to have a function that receives these two and return a new row type with their common properties. Then what?

Comment: @norbertpy well, type-level functions in haskell are called "type families", so maybe that will help, and they can be used in combination with type classes. Or you may just be looking for type classes. It's still not clear to me what you're trying to achieve, sorry.

Comment: @norbertpy It looks like you are looking for row polymorphism, which Haskell does not support.  Every field belongs to exactly one record type, and every record type has a fixed set of fields.  There are various halfhearted simulations of it though. [More info here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Extensible_record).